# How to increment arrival date of request by one ms if same

Tags: java, collections, puzzle

I need a java utility method in java (for my application which get thousands of request coming in a second), which has following feature. 
The request has arrivaltime in format of (DD-MM-YYYY-HH:MM:SS) and bucketNumber (1-100).

I want that if for same bucketNumber if same arrivaltime comes from request it should increment the value of arrivaltime of request by 1 miliisecond.

For example :

If for bucketNumber=1 arrival time for 1st, 2nd, 3rd request = 01-01-2016-10:00:00  (actually time till milli 01-01-2016-10:00:00:000) and a 4th request with 01-01-2016-10:00:01.

So for 2nd request the utility method will return 01-01-2016-10:00:00 (BUT this actually 01-01-2016-10:00:00:001)

and for 3rd request the utility method will return 01-01-2016-10:00:00 (BUT this actually 01-01-2016-10:00:00:002)

and for 4rd request the utility method will return 01-01-2016-10:00:01 only without performing any operation.

I don't want to keep a huge cache to perform this action (if I use set then I want to keep removing redundant the data as well).

```
//signature should be like below
Date getIncrementedArrivalTimeIfSame(Date arrivaltime, int bucketNumber ) {
//return incremented if equal else return original arrivaltime
}
```

Should I use a global map which has bucketNumber as key and a set which has arrival time? Please help me to implement this. This method will be invoked within synchronized block in a threadSafe way.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution.
I finaly used a map:

```
static Map<Integer, Date> arrivalTimeMap = new HashMap<>();
 static Date getIncrementedArrivalTimeIfEqual(Date arrivaltime,
            int bucketNumber) {

        Date lastArrivalTime =   arrivalTimeMap.put(bucketNumber, arrivaltime);
        if(lastArrivalTime != null && !lastArrivalTime.before(arrivaltime)){
            Date incrementedArrivalTime = incrementDateByMilliSeconds(
                    lastArrivalTime, 1); 
            arrivaltime = incrementedArrivalTime;

        }
        arrivalTimeMap.put(bucketNumber, arrivaltime);    
        return arrivaltime;
    }
```